# Calculate the orthogonal projection onto a vector $v$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to calculate the orthogonal projection of the vector
$$
v = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 4 \\ 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
on the $\text{span}(u_1,u_2)$ where
$$
u_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1/2 \\ 0 \\ 1/2
\end{pmatrix},
u_2 = \begin{pmatrix} 3/4 \\ 1/4 \\ -1/4
\end{pmatrix}
$$
My professor has provided the answers and says that the orthogonal projection can be calculated as
$$
p = \langle v,u_1 \rangle u_1 + \langle v,u_2 \rangle u_2
$$
however, normally, I would use the formula
$$
p = \frac{\langle v,u_1 \rangle u_1}{||u_1||^2} + \frac{\langle v,u_2 \rangle u_2}{||u_2||^2}
$$
so I don't understand the reason behind the provided answers. Do you mind explaining why? I do not know if it makes any difference but $u_1,u_2$ is an orthonormal basis which I have created by using the Gram-Schmidt Process for the basis $V = (v_1,v_2,v_3)$ where $v_1 = (1,0,1)^T, v_2 = (5,1,1)^T, v_3 = (4,-1,0)^T$

Comment: The first formula is valid if the vector onto you are projecting is a unit vector, is indeed a special case of the second formula you wrote.

Comment: But $u_1,u_2$ are not units vectors? So is the professor's answer wrong? I do not get the same result if I use the last formula as $||u_1||^2  \neq 1$ and $||u_2||^2 \neq 1$

Comment: Just use the second formula and you get the right result.

Comment: So my professors answers using the first formula is wrong?

Comment: Yes, i think... if the resut is different your prof is wrong :)